# Cannot understand solution (Turing Machine & Reduction)

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, computation-theory, turing-machines, reduction

[Please click this to see my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUuZE.jpg)

Hi.

About this question, I just can't understand its solution provided.

We know the complement of Atm = {`<M,W>` : M is TM and M does not accept W}
and Rtm as described in photo = {`<M,W>` : M is TM that rejects the input string W}

if we put `M,epsilon` into each of above,

```
the complement of Atm = M does not accept epsilon
Rtm = M rejects Epsilon
```

in either case, it makes sense to me, thus my perspective is
 is in Rtm and complement of Atm.
But answer says `<M,epsilon>` is NOT in Rtm but in complement of Atm

Why is that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: i guess they just mean that running forever is not the same as rejecting. rejecting is terminating with a "reject" status

Answer (score 0):

```
i guess they just mean that running forever is not the same as rejecting. rejecting is terminating with a "reject" status – Anton Knyazyev 14 mins ago
```

I think this answer is correct.